In Rust, can I restrict a generic only to types that can be trivially dropped?
I'm currently working on writing a Rust library which defines an allocator that can allocate a user-specified type. The definition looks something like this:
struct Allocator<T> { …fields… }

However, the nature of my sort of allocator is such that for anything it allocates, the destructors couldn't soundly be run upon deallocation (there's no safe order to do it in, and this is expected due to the way in which the allocator behaves). As such, the allocator is written to prevent the destructors of the data it allocates from running. It'll still release the memory, as usual for a deallocation; it simply just won't run Drop::drop on it first, neither for the allocated T itself nor for anything it recursively contains. The majority of useful use cases will have a T that can trivially be dropped, so this limitation doesn't matter in most cases – unless a user runs into it by accident without realising it exists (or without realising that their T does have side effects when dropped).
If a user attempts to create one of my allocators using a T that has nontrivial destructors (either directly via impl Drop for T or indirectly via a field it contains), then one of two possible outcomes occur, and I don't have control over which one:

If the type of T causes it to fail the drop check, due to containing a short-lived lifetime, the program will fail to compile, on the basis that it would be impossible to safely drop the Allocator. (This is rare in normal Rust programming, but somewhat more common with the types of T that are most likely to be used with the type of allocator I'm writing.)
If the type of T does not fail the drop check, because all its lifetimes are long-lived, the program will compile, but will not then actually run the destructor.

This isn't a particularly ergonomic API. Although it's sound as defined by Rust (because there is no guarantee that a destructor will ever run, and failing to run it is not a soundness violation), it is likely to be doing something that the user doesn't expect if they use a T with a nontrivial destructor – and what that "something" is is unclear, because the drop check is hard to understand and subject to change in future versions of Rust. I'd ideally like a way for the type system itself to say "this object doesn't do what you'd expect if you give it a type with a destructor" – if the user is sure they're OK with the destructor not running, it seems preferable to force them to use a ManuallyDrop<T> to document that, and if the user is not OK with the destructor not running, it would push them to use a more appropriate allocator type.
However, I haven't been able to find a way to express this (e.g. there doesn't seem to be a TrivialDrop trait in the standard library). There is std::mem::needs_drop, which is a const fn, but because it takes its argument as a generic parameter, it doesn't seem to be usable as a type constraint or in a where clause. (Even hacky attempted solutions like this one:
struct Allocator<T> where [(); std::mem::needs_drop::<T>() as usize]: From<[(); 0]>

fail because the ::<T> syntax isn't allowed on a const fn within a where clause, in addition to not looking very sensible in the documentation.)
Is there a way to restrict use of my allocator to cases where T can be trivially dropped? Or will I need to allow arbitrary T, and simply add warnings that it may cause a resource leak due to not running T's destructor, if it has one?

Not perfect but Copy types cannot have drop logic

There is also #![feature(generic_const_exprs)] which will allow the code you wrote.

Using the newly stabilized const_blocks feature, you can assert that the type is !needs_drop in the Drop impl (or anywhere really, your Allocator::new might be a better place).
struct Allocator<T> {
    inner: T
}

impl<T> Allocator<T> {
    fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        Self { inner }
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for Allocator<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        const { assert!(!std::mem::needs_drop::<T>()); }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let allocator = Allocator::new(String::new());
}

playground

And by "newly" you mean "yesterday" – no wonder I hadn't seen this before. I need to support versions of Rust that aren't quite that new, so I'll keep this question open/non-accepted in case another answer becomes available before Rust 1.79 becomes more widely used; but I'm planning to accept this once it becomes safe to assume that most users will have Rust 1.79 available.

This is not a valid usage of std::mem::needs_drop(), since, as explained in its documentation, it is intended purely as an optimization hint and may conservatively return true.

@ChayimFriedman According to OP, this is also only an "optimization" hint (in the sense that nor safety nor correctness are affected), since they already check safety through other means, they just want their users to not use types with a Drop impl since their allocator can't drop types.

If you're OK to rely on Rust 1.79 or later (released on 13 June 2024 – yesterday at the time of writing), then use the solution in @Filipe Rodrigues' answer. I will probably be accepting that answer once more Rust programmers have switched to that version.
In the meantime, inspired by that answer, and by the desugaring in the reference for the newly stabilised feature, I've found a solution that works for older Rust versions too: create a zero-sized structure with an associated constant that performs the assert:
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct AssertTrivialDrop<T>(PhantomData<T>);
impl<T> Default for AssertTrivialDrop<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let _ = Self::_DROPS_TRIVIALLY;
        AssertTrivialDrop(PhantomData::default())
    }
}
impl<T> AssertTrivialDrop<T> {
    const _DROPS_TRIVIALLY: () = {
        assert!(!core::mem::needs_drop::<T>())
    };
}

then add a field _assert_trivial_drop: AssertTrivialDrop<T> to Allocator<T>, and initialise it using Allocator::default() in Allocator<T>'s constructor.
This works as long as there's at least one use of the constant (in this case, it's in AssertTrivialDrop::default()), and will cause a compile-time error (evaluation of `allocator::AssertTrivialDrop::<T>::_DROPS_TRIVIALLY` failed, with the appropriate type substituted for T). There's no runtime performance penalty, because the added field has zero size.

You can have the check without the need to add a field to Allocator: Playground

This is not a valid usage of std::mem::needs_drop(), since, as explained in its documentation, it is intended purely as an optimization hint and may conservatively return true.

@ChayimFriedman A false-positive true is fine here because the programmer has a way to work around it (enclosing the type in ManuallyDrop to reflect that they're fine with any destructor not running), and the code is sound regardless of the check passing or failing (it just does something that might be unexpected).

@ais523 The problem is that code that worked in one version of the compiler might break in the next.
